# How to list the content of cells depending on the value of another cell

Tags: excel, date, cell

I have an excel file to organize 4 projects (a,b,c,d), each project being assigned tasks, and everything being organized along a calendar:

[image]
Given start and end dates I want to:

1. have the number of days assigned to each project (I already did that
   with COUNTIFS)
2. isolate and list the corresponding tasks, in a way similar to that:

[image: final_cell_list]

it must have to do with conditional display but I have'nt found a way through.
Thanks,

Comment: Try to un-merge the Cells with "meeting" in them, and then make this into individual cells (eg 2x meeting) that you can run your countif on.

Comment: Do you mean to both check in the countif for the project's name in F and for the task's name in GHI?

Comment: Yes, but don't have it as G11:I12 (merged) have them as single cells. eg in H11 - meeting, H12 Meeting, then you can countif on the column H.

Comment: Actually looking at it, just remove the merged cells in the columns G:I and make one column (maybe H), then each row can be counted separately with your countif, if you still want the cells to be wide for formatting then just make the cells width wider.

Answer (score 0):

so, unmerging all cells, and given standard predefined cell contents, it is possible to count the occurence with COUNTIFS as described in this screenshot

[image: count_cell_occurence]

Comment: Yeah, looks Good, and like you have answered your own question!!  :D Do you need any more help?

Comment: well, it looks like what I want to do cannot be done that easily in excel, I am going to use R shiny to have a user-friendly excel interface and much more funtionality